# Capture Screenshot of whole scrolling Page in Xamarinforms

Tags: c#, xamarin, screenshot, mvvmcross, xamarin-forms-4

I am using Xam.Plugin.Screenshot to take screenshot of a page, but unfortunately I am unable to capture the whole view, it's only capturing the content that is on the screen, not the content that is below in scrollview .... I am using below code to capture Screenshot. Please tell me which way to go to get a complete screent shot of all the content in

```
await CrossScreenshot.Current.CaptureAndSaveAsync();
```

Comment: This behavior is as expected, it will only capture the current content on the screen , there is no method to achieve what you want .

Comment: Is'nt there any other plugin or method that allow me to capture he whole content in scrollview ?

Comment: Capturing screenshot does not meet your requirement, you could try to record your screen , solution refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183292/how-can-i-record-the-screen-of-my-device.

Comment: Actually I need to capture and save image of the whole content in the scrollview, video is not a solution for me you can say .....

Comment: Short answer : impossible .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a trick
Take Partial Screenshots of Your Xamarin.Forms App
Nuget Package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageFromXamarinUI

**XML**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="root" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White">
   your all code here...
</StackLayout>
```

**C#**

```
using ImageFromXamarinUI;
 

    var stream = await root2.CaptureImageAsync();            
    var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "screenshot2.png");
    if (File.Exists(file))
        File.Delete(file);
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
    await fs.FlushAsync();
    }
    return file;
```